# How to submit form only one check box is selected using java script

Tags: javascript

**on edit button click a want to submit form only if one check box checked,don't submit when 0 or more than 2 check box checked**

**my below code is not working**

```
$("#editbtn_id").click(function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    var checkbox_value = "";
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    });

    if (ischecked) {
        checkbox_value += $(this).val();
        cnt = cnt + 1;


        if (cnt == 0 || cnt > 1) {
            alert(cnt);
            alert("Please select one Test case");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/editSingletest/{{ testcase.id }}" method="post" onsubmit="return" >
<input type="checkbox"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but it looks like you actually need radio buttons.

Comment: "*...more than 2 check box checked...*" that means 2 should be ok? the question title seeems to be in-congruent with your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by following code

```
$("#editbtn_id").click(function(){
 var cnt=0;
 var checkbox_checked_count = 0;
 var form_submit = false;
   $(":checkbox").each(function () {
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         checkbox_checked_count++
       }
    });
if(checkbox_checked_count == 1) {
    form_submit = true;
}
else if(checkbox_checked_count > 1) {
 alert("Please select one Test case");
}
alert(form_submit)
$("form").submit();    
});
```

Check working example here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQPDY/)

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is in the wrong loop, should be something like this:

```
$("#editbtn_id").click(function(){
       var cnt=0;
       var checkbox_value = "";
       $(":checkbox").each(function () {
          var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
          if (ischecked){
                checkbox_value += $(this).val();
                cnt=cnt + 1 ;
          }
        });



        if(cnt==0 || cnt > 1){ ... }    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#editbtn_id").click(function (e) {
    if($('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 1){
        $('form').submit();
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

for 'form' use your form selector